# Is try catch in a view bad practice?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, razor, try-catch

In an MVC3 application, is it considered bad practice to use a try catch block inside of a razor block `@{    }` in the `.cshtml` view?

Comment: @SLaks - As you said, there is not a good reason for this and there would be logic in the wrong place - I have not done it yet but just wanted a little back and forth on it. The reason is that I realized I had an exception in the view from associating an object which had a valid foreign at one point, but that foreign object had been removed from the database. Here is an example of an association: `phase.Container = containers.Where(cont => cont.ContainerId == phase.ContainerId).SingleOrDefault();`. I will have to handle the exceptions here. Should all linq be surrounded with try catch?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Very much so.

Views should not contain any real logic; anything that might throw an exception belongs in the controller.

Comment: Blanket statements like this are never accurate. Are you saying that it's bad form to put any code in a view? Then why does Razor exist? And if you have code in a view, there can certainly be cases where exceptions (such as the unavailability of an external file) need to be handled.

Comment: What if it's a shared partial view and there's no controller for it?

Comment: @MaksimVi.: Then you should use a child action instead.

Comment: @SLaks for a 'shared' logic? What if this shared partial view is shared between hundreds of views?

Comment: @MaksimVi.: So? You can still use a single child action (in a shared controller) instead.

Comment: Well I guess introducing a new controller to handle a small try/catch logic in a shared view is one way to do it, but seems like an overkill to me.

Comment: Isn't "Blanket statements like this are never accurate" co-incidentally a blanket statement? FYI, I agree with him in this case.

Comment: So, how do you prevent the view from loading if there's an error in the controller?

Answer (score 8):

```
@{
try
{
    <td>
        @((TradeType)Enum.Parse(typeof(TradeType), item.AppCode)).GetDescription();
    </td>
}
catch
{
    <td>@item.AppCode
    </td>
}
}
```

Comment: Not really an answer to the question: The question was if it was good practice, not how it's done.

Comment: While this may answer the question, you did not leave behind any explanation as to why this works. This answer does not add much value for later visitors that may have the same problem. Please expand your answer to include some explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Well your use depends on the specifics of your application however you should try to keep your views as bare as possible. Ideally code validity would be verified in the controller and never passed to the view.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put such code in Views. Views should be only for your display markup as much as possible. You can put that try catch in your controller action method which supplies the data to a view.

```
public ActionResult GetUser(int id)
{

  try
  {
    //Get the ViewModel and return the correct View.
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    //log the error
    return View("YourErrorView");
  }   

}
```

Keep in mind that one of the things MVC emphasizing is separation of concerns. Views should be clean and readable Markup.

Answer (score 1):

I would say so.  The optimal route would to have the Model passed to the View validated by the controller before it reaches the view.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good thing to do. The MVC framework is designed to seperate the view with the logic. So keep the logic where it should be, in the controller.