# How To Handle Error Inside @() Tag In MVC View; Also Why DivideByZero Error?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I don't understand this error!  I have a JavaScript function where I am assigning a value to a string at runtime, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    RefreshDashButtons() {
...

    Line 532:         dash10FTEs = "@(branch.FTEs.ToString())";
    Line 533:         dash10TurnoversOpen = @(branch.Turnovers.ToString()) + " | " + @(branch.OpenPositions.ToString());
    Line 534:         dash10Style = "@(branch.MTDDash10StyleOV)";
    Line 535:     }
    Line 536: }
...

    }
</script>
```

When execution gets to Line 534, I get a DivideByZeroException.  Here is the Stack Trace:

```
System.DivideByZeroException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147352558
  Message=Attempted to divide by zero.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Decimal.FCallDivide(Decimal& d1, Decimal& d2)
       at System.Decimal.op_Division(Decimal d1, Decimal d2)
       at ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Projects_VS2010\Dashboard\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:line 534
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()
       at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
       at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
       at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17()
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
  InnerException: null
```

This apparently is some kind of internal .NET error, which is not my main concern (although it is weird).  What I'd like to do is handle the error gracefully, or even just absorb it.  Can anyone suggest how to do that with .NET code that is inside JavaScript?  I've tried commenting out the line; but then the error occurs on the previous line, which is also just assigning a string.

I've stepped through the code, and everything is fine until I hit this line. At runtime, branch.MTDDash10StyleOV = "bbtext-normal".  That is, as of Line 533.

Hope this helps?

Comment: Where is `serverString` defined and assigned to?

Comment: He actually meant: Show us that code.

Comment: Then it would have to be assigned to the viewbag or model and accessed via `Model.SomeProperty` or `ViewBag.SomeProperty` because as it is there it looks like a variable local to your cshtml page.

Comment: It was. I was trying to keep it simple.  "serverString" is a string property on a class that was passed in the ViewBag from the controller.  At runtime, the property does have a valid value; I've checked that much.

Comment: The line that the debugger breaks on is not necessarily the line that throws the exception. Something is throwing an exception before reaching your script element.

Comment: I didn't think you'd want all that. So in the controller, I have a class called branch that is assigned a string, like this:   branch.MTDDashStyle = "bbtext-normal";

Comment: Hang on, I'll edit my post to include more info... :)

Comment: I don't understand why you have logic in your view in the first place.  If you need logic to derive a value, put that logic in the model or whatever is used to populate the model.  This will prevent a lot of issues in views.

Comment: `try..catch` can be used within the view, similar to `if..else`, etc. But, do note: [Is try catch in a view bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845391/is-try-catch-in-a-view-bad-practice)

Comment: Jonathan, branch.MTDDash10StyleOV is just a string.  Nothing custom.  Erik, you are absolutely right!  I need to move all this stupid JavaScript back up to the controller. Lol!  I just don't get how a simple string assignment can throw a math error like that. Grr!

Comment: Jonathan:  Agreed, try..catch in the view would be a hack at best.  But how would I even do it around Line 534 above?